# jQuery Append not using HTML Tags

Tags: jquery, html

I have a strange issue, I'm using jQuery to append some HTML to an h1 tag.  I'm using a CMS here at work that I don't have access to the backend, so I have to do some trickery to make things work.  My code I'm using is...

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() { 
var html = '<span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-style: italic; display: block;">Tools to help make your farm profitable and successful</span>';
$('.mainContent h1').first().html(html); });
</script>
```

Now I've tested this script on jsfiddle and it works just fine, it appends to the H1 tag and everything looks proper.  When the actual page loads it, however, it's treating the entire html variable as a string and it's actually printing out the HTML (tags and all) instead of rendering it as you'd expect.

You can see what I mean [here](https://www.ncat.edu/caes/ag-savvy/)

I've attempted many different variations of it, but still can't seem to get it to work on the page.  Any ideas?  Thank you in advance.

Comment: The code you've posted seems to work, even through the console on your site. You'll have to be more precise with what exactly you're doing, as it stands now it's not reproducible

Comment: _"I'm using a CMS here "_ This is probably what's sanitizing the input and converting your HTML to HTML entities

Comment: You're not actually calling `append()` in your sample code here, either. But yes, I'd imagine that wherever you're entering this script, at least the `<` chars are being converted to entities.

Comment: View source on the page, you'll see `<script type="text/javascript">// 
$(function() { var html = '&lt;span style = "font-size: 10pt; font-style: italic; display: block;"&gt;Tools to help make your farm profitable and successful&lt;/span&gt;'; $('.mainContent h1').first().append(html); });`

Comment: try encoding your string like this:
`&#x3C;span style = &#x22;font-size: 10pt; font-style: italic; display: block;&#x22;&#x3E;Tools to help make your farm profitable and successful&#x3C;/span&#x3E;`

Comment: EXACTLY!  The code will execute fine, even via the console...HOWEVER...when run from the page, you can see the HTML just being spit out as plain text.  I changed it from .html to .append as well.  I've tried many different ways, but it still continues to spit out the raw HTML code.

Comment: I tried encoding it the way suggested by Ivan-San, but still no luck.  I don't want to have to create a stylesheet for each and every page JUST to add a sub heading.  They've made a ton of changes to this CMS in the past weeks, that they haven't communicated with all of us.  So...yeah....but...I think, while typing this, I may have thought of a work around!

Comment: I suppose you add this code to the article text in your CMS's editor. It might happen that it never reaches the database because it is sanitized before. If you look at the page source you will see, that nothing from your javascript code is there - just the string, with entities. The rest is stripped away. Thus nothing is "executed" actually. I don't think you can get this working. Your only chance is to find an exploit in your CMS. @Ivan-San's suggestion was the most likely one, but you should try encoding the whole stuff this way, not only the string. You could try percent-encoding too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CMS is likely interfering when it detects the angle brackets in the string. Here's an alternate way of creating DOM elements with jQuery which doesn't use any angle brackets:

```
$(function() { 
    var span = $(document.createElement('span')).text('Tools to help make your farm profitable and successful').css({
            display: 'block',
            fontSize: '10pt',
            fontStyle: 'italic',
        });
    $('.mainContent h1').first().empty().append(span)
});
```

The above should work, assuming you want to eliminate the text `Become Ag Savvy` from the page.

If you want to keep it, and merely append the new span to it, delete the call to `.empty()`.

This is, of course, entirely contingent on the CMS keeping the `<script>` tags intact (and not converting them to `&lt;script&gt;`).

Comment: That worked perfectly!  Thank you Pete!  I should have thought of that but they have me doing a million other things too.  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `document.createElement()` to create your `span` tag? Something like:

```
<body class="mainContent">

    <h1></h1>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {

        var el = document.createElement('span');
        el.style.cssText = "font-size: 10pt; font-style: italic; display: block;";
        el.innerHTML = "Tools to help make your farm profitable and successful";

        $('.mainContent h1').first().html(el); 

    });
    </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try and sneak around the CMS' encoder by using plain vanilla JavaScript for most of the code:

```
var elem = document.createElement('span');
elem.setAttribute("style","font-size: 10pt; font-style: italic; display: block");
elem.innerHTML = 'Tools to help make your farm profitable and successful';
$('body').append(elem);
```